# Silverlight P2P App (In Browser) - Will we get RTMFP?

Tags: flash, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, p2p, rtmfp

Ok so from all my research I'm fairly positive P2P is not possible in Silverlight 4 (in browser).

Flash can do P2P using Stratus/RTMFP which I believe uses UDP hole punching and a Stratus server to help initialize the connection.

Is there any plans for Microsoft to add some kind of p2p rendezvous service in the future?  Can we get a definitive yes/no on whether or not p2p is possible in SL4.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for (as I'm late to the party for this older question), but [CodePlex](http://silverlightp2p.codeplex.com/) has a P2P library  -- though it looks as though this library has a dependency on Window Live Messenger.

Assuming your Silverlight 4 app doesn't have to be cross-platform to Mac, you may be able to get to the Winsock APIs either directly or through some sort of COM wrapper.

Answer (score -2):

No, you cannot get a definitive answer about future Silverlight features up on StackOverflow.

If you're interested in seeing this feature implemented I suggest you vote open up a [Connect Issue](http://tinyurl.com/SilverlightBug) and vote up the [UserVoice issue](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/460973-p2p-peer-to-peer-system-net-peertopeer-namespace).

Comment: "Can we get a definitive yes/no on whether or not p2p is possible in SL4."

I didn't ask for a definitive answer about the future.